# Actionscript - Flex mobile thread while loading data?

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I am using Flash builder actionscript 3 Flex mobile.
I have a very heavy function that loads data from the local device and creates many graphic elements. While this function runs, the device freezes for 6 seconds or so.
I want to show a progress bar and let the device continue working, is there any way I can use threading to do this ? Other ideas are also welcome.

Thanks, Koby.

Comment: Please show some code.  Have you run this through the profiler [or other tools to determine what is causing the slowdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that at which function application getting freeze. Before that function call a progress bar. Create a progress bar in a pop up mode & call it. After 6 seconds(Not recommended) or getting the data just call removeallpopups() method. So now you can set the label in progress bar as "Loding..."

Sample code

```
<mx:ProgressBar id="sampleProgressBar" styleName="Calib16Blue"
                    indeterminate="true" labelPlacement="left"
                    label="{theMessage}"/>
```

Call this mxml by creating a pop up.

Answer (score 0):

To do 'proper' muiltithreading you need to use the `Worker` Class ([Documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)), however the `SQLConnection` [class](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/simple_sql_database.html) and `FileStream` [class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#openAsync%28%29) have asynchronous methods that fit into the normal Actionscript event listener cycle and operate in "the background". Allowing the rest of the app to load when they're still pending.